# Password validation in Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am working on a sample project to have a deeper understanding of `DDD`. Let's say we have a case that the user needs to change their password.

Generally the current password is changed by providing the the `current password` and the `new password`. Now what I want to check is that the `current password` passed as API parameter, is actually the one stored in `DB`.

Generally passwords are stored as Hashes and generally there are libraries like `Spring` that provide an abstraction to work with.

Now the password matching is a `Domain Concept` so should be a part of the `User Entity` but the way to match the password would depend on the algorithm and maybe hence is `Infrastructure`.

So where does the password matching logic go?

Does the controller match the password and then makes a call to the

```
UserEntity.ChangePassword(newPassword)
```

or does the userEntity has a method

```
UserEntity.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword) {

    PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator(); // where PasswordValidator is a framework class 
    boolean doesMatch = validator.validate(currentPassInDB, oldPassword);
    if (!doesMatch)
        return; // throw error
    this.currentPassInDB = doSomething(newPassword);
}
```

If do go with the approach 2, then the framework classes would leak in to the Domain Class. I am confused here. Would password be a `value object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would most likely declare an interface in the domain for encrypting or validating a password. That interface would get implemented in the infrastructure layer.

The AR itself could have a dependency on the interface:

`user.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, validator);`

or you could implement the logic within a domain service which would orchestrate the use case, decoupling the AR from that dependency (I prefer the former).

That's similar to how Vaughn Vernon handled authentication, by declaring the [`EncryptionService`](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_identityaccess/src/main/java/com/saasovation/identityaccess/domain/model/identity/EncryptionService.java) interface which is then leveraged in the [`AuthenticationService`](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_identityaccess/src/main/java/com/saasovation/identityaccess/domain/model/identity/AuthenticationService.java) domain service.

Comment: Yeah I thought about injecting the service as a `method argument`, but what I thought was `"The way to generate and match passwords is Domain Information"` and why should the `Application Services layer` (the API controllers) inform the `AR` on how to do that. For example: If I have two controllers that provide two different implementations of the `Validator` then the whole model would just end up failing because no passwords would match.

Comment: @iam.Carrot You could extend this argument to virtually any kind of infrastructure services. What if an application service used an in-memory implementation of a `UserRepository` where another used a sql-server-backed implementation? It's up to the developer to make sure that the composition root of the application makes sense. Furthermore, it's not the controller that would be passing the service, but the application's service (granted, both could be the same depending).

Comment: "he way to generate and match passwords is Domain Information" If your point of view is that hashing passwords should be domain knowledge then make the implementation part of the domain.

Comment: Valid point on that `UserRepository` . Great thanks. Would it be possible to share an insight on how can I make the implementation hashing passwords as part of the domain. This is just for an insight for a better understanding. Thanks again

Comment: @iam.Carrot It would just be a matter of writing the `PasswordValidator` implementation in the domain package ;)

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for all the help. Much appreciated